# RNG should ignore numers that have already been given [Python]

Tags: python, random, generator

I'm using a random number generater to select a question from a list at random, if the question has already been answered it should skip and reroll until it gets a number that hasn't been given yet.

It works until the options become too limited. It'll roll ~4 times. If it still doesn't have a number that hasn't been given before, it'll give an "index out of range" error.

Sample:

```
from random import randint
counter = 0 # Max value, count the amount of questions in the list
done = [] # Already been rolled, ignore these values
list = open('questions.txt').readlines()

for l in list:
    counter +=1

try:
   # While there are less values in <done> than <counter>, roll and add to list
   while len(done) < counter:
       question = randint(1,counter)
       while question in done:
           print('Skipped [%i]' % question) # Check if ignored
           question = randint(1,counter) # Reroll
       else:
           # Add to list so it knows the question has already been asked
           done.append(question) # Add to list with given values
   else:
       print('Finished!\n')
except Exception as e:
   print(e) # Show error if any
```

I have no clue what i've done wrong, please help.

Thanks :)

Comment: You should be using `random.sample`, by the way.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "shuffle".  Use `random.shuffle` and then just pop items off.

Comment: `random.randint()` includes both end points. So sometimes you get the last point: out of range. Use `randrange()`, or, better check above comments to be really pythonic.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name: that shadows the built-in `list` type. It may work ok sometimes, but other times it can leads to bugs that produce cryptic error messages. Also, it's very inefficient to use a loop to get the size of a list. Just use the `len()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be even simpler, you actually don't need your counter.

Let's say you have a list of question :

```
import random
questions = ['how are you ?', 'happy now ?', 'Another question ?']
```

Then you will print one of those questions :

```
question = random.choice(foo)
print question
```

Then just delete it from the list :

```
# del questions[questions.index(question)]
questions.remove(question)
```

Here you go ! ;)

Comment: Using shuffle is more efficient than deleting items inside the list because when you delete any item apart from the last one all subsequent items have to be moved down. Sure, this operation is fast because it happens at C speed, but it's still wasteful to do it if you don't really need it. Also, doing `questions.index(question)` has to perform a linear scan of the list to find the item.

Comment: And `del questions[questions.index(question)]` is `questions.remove(question)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't understand why using shuffle will be better ? Actually, we need to pick one question that doesn't have to be asked again. So even using `shuffle`, we will have to pick a question and then delete it from the original list.

Comment: @iFlo We don't need to delete anything. We shuffle once, outside the loop, and then we just iterate over the shuffled list.

Comment: Did what iFlow said. It works, so i'm happy. Still learning python so thanks for the help. Taking all solutions in consideration though. See what works best.